# Will this custom element work? I've taken it off Material Design lite

Tags: javascript, material-design, shadow-dom, custom-element

```
    class CardElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: open});

        let div = document.createElement('div');

        let div_main = div;
        div_main.className = "demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp";
        shadow.appendChild(div_main);
        let div_sec = div;
        div_sec.className = "mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand";
        div_sec.style.background = this.getAttribute('src');
        shadow.appendChild(div_sec);
        let h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.className = "mdl-card__title-text";
        h2.innerHTML = this.getAttribute('text');
        shadow.appendChild(h2);
        let div_three = div;
        div_three.className = "mdl-card__supporting-text";
        div_three.innerHTML = this.getAttribute('support-text');
        shadow.appendChild(div_three);
        let div_border = div;
        div_border.className ="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border";
        shadow.appendChild(div_border);
        let anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.className = "mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect";
        shadow.appendChild(anchor);
    }
}
customElements.define('card-element', CardElement);
}
```

I tried to make the card component (https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#cards-section) into a custom element like the above given code. But couldn't see an appropriate output. Any help is appreciated since I've just started to develop applications for the web.

```
<card-element src="img.jpg" text="Inside" support-text="Can you see what I've done here!"></card-element>
```

And this is showing me an error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'attachShadow' on 'Element': The provided value 'function open() { [native code] }' is not a valid enum value of type ShadowRootMode.
    at new CardElement`

So could you let me why it isn't working or how I should be tackling this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You should use simple or double quotes with `open` in `attachShadow()`:

```
let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
```

Comment: okay, that helped but only a few of the components, the H2, the div_border and the anchor are visible in the #shadowRoot